# Connect from mysql client from one host to multiple host with .my.cnf client file

Tags: mysql, database

I have configured multiple databases in my.cnf file and trying to use them via command line mysql.

My config looks like this:

`[client]
host=abaabs
user=asdads
password=vxcvx
database=zdxew`


`[client_read]
host=12312
user=34534
password=546456
database=6786786`

And when i say mysql on command line i get by default client config as the default database. How do I select the second database on mysql cmd?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On command line `$ mysql --defaults-group-suffix=_read` for the client_read database.

You may wish to make an alias for a given database using something like:

`$ alias myreaddb "mysql --defaults-group-suffix=_read"`

Comment: There should be an equal sign in the alias command in bash, <code>alias myreaddb="mysql --defaults-group-suffix=_read" </code>